# What's wrong with my modified merge sort implementation?

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to write a modified merge sorting as an excercise. But i am stuck in why my code doesn't work and i cannot se where is the problem?!  any hint or help is appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public class MergeSort {

    public static void mergeSort(int[] list) {
        mergeSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
    }

    private static void mergeSort(int[] list, int low, int high) {

        if (low < high) {

            int middle = (high + low) / 2;

            mergeSort(list, low, middle);

            mergeSort(list, middle + 1, high);

            int[] temp = merge(list, low, high);
            System.arraycopy(temp, 0, list, low, high - low + 1);
        }
    }

    private static int[] merge(int[] list, int low, int high) {

        int low1 = low;
        int high1 = high;
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        int end_low = mid;
        int start_high = mid + 1;

        while ((low <= end_low) && (start_high <= high1)) {
            if (list[low] < list[start_high]) {
                low++;
            } else {
                int temp = list[high - low + 1];
                for (int k = start_high - 1; k >= low; k--) {
                    list[k + 1] = list[k];
                }
                list[low] = temp;
                low++;
                end_low++;
                start_high++;
            }
        }

        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = { 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, -2, 3, 14, 12, -5 };
        mergeSort(list);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"any hint or help is appreciate."*.  Hint: use a debugger Luke.

Comment: On the mergeSort method, you are not assigning the values returned by the merge method to the low and high variables. I didn't run the code but thats the first thing that caught my eye.